# React Navigation Redux Authentication Keeps Stacking

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to do the navigation for the authentication of my React Native app, and I'm using a splash screen to do it. But when the user logs in I send them back to the splash screen, which redirects them to the main screen of the app as long as they're authenticated. However, I'm getting this weird bug where it's going to the main screen before going to splash screen, and glitching out for a few seconds. Here's my code:

AppNavigation:

```
  const PrimaryNav = StackNavigator({
  SplashScreen: { screen: SplashScreen },
  RegistrationScreen: { screen: RegistrationScreen },
  LoginScreen: { screen: LoginScreen },
  MainScreen: { screen: MainScreen }
}, {
  // Default config for all screens
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'SplashScreen'
})
```

ReduxNavigation:

```
function ReduxNavigation (props) {
  const { dispatch, nav } = props
  const navigation = ReactNavigation.addNavigationHelpers({
    dispatch,
    state: nav
  })

  return <PrimaryNav navigation={navigation} />
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ nav: state.nav })
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxNavigation)
```

SplashScreen:

```
class SplashScreen extends Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    const route = this.props.isLoggedIn ? 'LoggedOutNav' : 'LoggedInNav'
    const action = NavigationActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: route })]
    })
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(action)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <OuterSplashContainer>
        <SplashImage
          source={Images.splashImage}
        />
      </OuterSplashContainer>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isLoggedIn: () => isLoggedIn(state)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(SplashScreen)
```

And then the important part of LoginScreen:

```
componentWillReceiveProps (newProps) {
    if (newProps.user.token) {
      const { navigation } = this.props
      navigation.navigate('SplashScreen')
    }
  }
```

[Here's an image of what is going wrong.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyuP2.gif)

Do you have any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: The weird thing I see here is that you are triggering the navigation at componentWillReceiveProps of LoginScreen. After you receive your token (from the server I guess), I think you should trigger the navigation without changing the props of the LoginScreen.

Comment: Like in the saga or something?

Comment: Maybe. I'm not so familiar with Saga and native (I use the original react), but if I were using react for doing that I wouldn't trigger events at componentWill* lifecycles.

Comment: How would you do it?

Comment: If I were using AJAX, I would trigger a Redux action just after I've got the token. Then, the React-Router component which is listening to the store  would change the page I'm showing.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the navigation stack instead of just navigating to Splash Screen in LoginScreen componentWillReceiveProps?